# Cómo hacer que mi programa siga ejecutando mientras está esperando un ReadKey()

Tags: c#

Mi inquietud es la siguiente.
Si tengo un programa que quiero que, mientras espera (por capricho) a que presione una determinada tecla imprima una sucesión de puntos por consola hasta que el usuario introduzca la tecla correcta, a qué proceso/método puedo recurrir?

Aquí está un ejemplo de código que he ido moldeando poco a poco

```
  Console.Write("Presione la tecla [Enter] para empezar ");
        bool flag = false;
        ConsoleKey Enter;

        while (flag == false) {

            for (int contador = 0; contador < 10; contador++)
            {
                Console.Write(".");
                Thread.Sleep(20);
            }

            Enter = Console.ReadKey().Key;

                if (flag == false)
                {                        
                    if (Enter == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                    {
                        flag = true;
                    }
                }
            
        }
//Salida por consola deseada: Presione la tecla [Enter] para empezar .......................................
...............................................
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quizá te ayude  Console.KeyAvailable   para ir imprimiendo los puntos mientras no se presione una tecla. Apenas se presione una  tecla  Console.KeyAvailable devuelve true sale del loop y puedes leer que  tecla fue y en funcion a eso salir o seguir esperando.

```
    Console.Write("Presione la tecla [Enter] para empezar ");
    bool flag = false;
    ConsoleKey Enter;

    while (flag == false) {

        while (Console.KeyAvailable == false)
        {
            Console.Write(".");
            Thread.Sleep(20);
        }

        Enter = Console.ReadKey().Key;

            if (flag == false)
            {                        
                if (Enter == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
        
    }
```